# Interpretation of Impulse Response Functions for VAR models using Log First Differences

Tags: econometrics, time-series, r

I am exploring a VAR model with 9 variables but for simplicity let us consider a model with only two variables and one lag. The VAR model would look something like this:
$$
y_t = \alpha_{11}y_{t-1} + \alpha_{12}x_{t-1} + \epsilon_y
$$
$$
x_t = \alpha_{21}y_{t-1} + \alpha_{22}x_{t-1} + \epsilon_x
$$
I first take natural logarithms of both variables and then take first differences to address non-stationary of the time series. The first equation (for the sake of brevity) would look like this
$$
\log(y_t)-\log(y_{t-1}) = \beta_{11}\left[\log(y_{t-1})-\log(y_{t-2})\right] + \beta_{12}\left[\log(x_{t-1})-\log(x_{t-2})\right] + \xi_y
$$
**How would I interpret an impulse response analysis that shocks $\xi_y$?** If I plotted the impulse response, would it show me the impact of a 1% increase in $\log(y_t)-\log(y_{t-1})$ on 
$\log(x_t)-\log(x_{t-1})$ or would it just be the impact of a 1% increase in $y_t$ on $x_t$ at time $t$?

One of my plots looks like this (note I just use `logdiff("variable")` as labels, this may not be correct, it is just an IRF on the above system):

[image]

Comment: Hi: I can't help much but, if you differenced to obtain stationarity, then you may have cointegrated variables which implies an error correction model. I'm not positive but I don't think an impulse response analysis is possible when there's error correction because there are two different things being effected by the shock. But hopefully someone else who knows more  can say more about this. Or check out Enders or Hamilton. There might be something in those about this case.

Comment: I left out Lutkepohl as a reference. It's been a long time since I looked at VARS but if your not familar with that one,  it's much more focused on VARS than Hamilton and much more theoretical and detailed compared to Enders.